# iOS UITextField resignFirstResponder issue

Tags: ios, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

In my app, on registration screen, I have `tableView` which containes `UITextField` in each cell and Submit button in a footer. Everything works fine except when I enter value in the last `TextField` and hit submit button (Without resigning a keyboard). My function does not show a value because value is only entered when text editing is ended. I am using Delegate to get a value.

**My code is:

In customcell.m:**

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([textField.text length] >0) {
    [self.cellImageview setImage:editImage];
    }
    else{
    [self.cellImageview setImage:defaultImage];
    }
    [_delegate signUpTableCell:self didUpdateValue:textField.text inTextField:textField];
}
```

In my viewController:

```
-(void)signUpTableCell:(SignUpTableCell *)cell didUpdateValue:(NSString *)value inTextField:(UITextField *)textField    {
    NSLog(@"cell:%@    value: %@  textfield value:%@ ", cell, value, textField.text);
    [registerDictionary setValue:value forKey:textField.placeholder];
    NSLog(@"registerDictionary:%@", registerDictionary);
}
```

**Problem:**
Last textField value is nil when I click on submit button, probably because 
`-(void)signUpTableCell:(SignUpTableCell *)cell didUpdateValue:(NSString *)value inTextField:(UITextField *)textField` 
does not get a call unless textField ends editing. If I click in empty place and resign a keyboard it works just fine. Is there a work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to manually call `resignFirstResponder()` when clicking on the button?

Comment: Yes I did, did not work. It resigns first responder but can't get value

Comment: So your keyboard actually goes away and your `textFieldDidEndEditing()` method is being called but `didUpdateValue()` is not called? Can you check if by manually calling `resignFirstResponder()` any of those methods are called?

Answer (score 1):

Add below code to in submit button :

```
[self.view endEditing:yes];
```

or use

```
[self.yourTableview.scrollView endEditing:yes];
```

Comment: Already did this but still I wouldn't get value in registerDictionary array

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by making few changes in my code. I had used `[self.view endEditing:yes];` after I get values from `registerDictionary` . Stupid of me.